# Upsampling datetime - ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit

Tags: indexing, resampling, valueerror

I get the error below when I try to upsample...

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

df1=pd.read_csv("C:/Codes/test.csv")
df1['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df1 = df1.set_index(['Date'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2 = df1.Gen.resample('H').ffill()
```

**I get this error...ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit. Please advise.**

My test.csv is a simple file with two columns containing these 5 records

Date|Gen
----|----
5/1/2017|Ggulf
5/2/2017|Ggulf
5/1/2017|Nelson
5/3/2017|Ggulf
5/4/2017|Nelson

Answer (score 2):

An index needs to have unique values. Your first record and third record have the same date '5/1/2017' which makes it impossible to set the date column as an index column.